# Populate a table with an array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an html table and I have an array in JavaScript.  I'm able to populate the table correctly.  The only issue is, I'm adding divs inside the td with an onclick event.

```
var workout = wo["workout"];

for(i=0;i<workout.length;i++){
    for(j=0;j<workout[i].length;j++){
        for(k=0;k<workout[i][j].length;k++){

            var td = document.getElementById(i+"-"+j);

            var closediv = document.createElement("div");
            closediv.className = "closediv";
            closediv.innerHTML = "x";

            closediv.onclick = function () {
                console.log(workout[i][j][k].id);
            };

            var exdiv = document.createElement("div");
            exdiv.id = workout[i][j][k].id;
            exdiv.className = workout[i][j][k].extype;
            exdiv.innerHTML = workout[i][j][k].exercise;
            exdiv.appendChild(closediv);

            td.appendChild(exdiv);
        }
    }
}
```

The id works correctly here:

```
exdiv.id = workout[i][j][k].id;
```

The id doesn't work when I have it here:

```
closediv.onclick = function () {
                console.log(workout[i][j][k].id);
            };
```

Please let me know what I've done wrong

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION**

Try this code instead:

```
closediv.onclick = function () {
   console.log(this.parentNode.id);
});
```

**DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t69vmve0/1/) for demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I think its closure loop issue.

if you want to get proper value one of the work around can be :

```
 closediv.onclick = function () {
     (function(i, j, k) {
         console.log(workout[i][j][k].id);
      )(i, j, k);
 };
```